# get DOCUMENT_ROOT in flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm working on a project in AS3 that connects to a PHP file. I need everything done dynamically so i need a way to get the document_root in flash, like i would in php (`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`).

is this possible? any idea how?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just parse `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` into the SWF via FlashVars.

```
<object width="" height="">
    <param name="flashvars" value="docroot=<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>" />
    <embed width="" height="" src="file.swf?docroot=<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>" />
</object>
```

And then in AS3:

```
var parsed:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
var docRoot:String = parsed.docroot;

// do stuff with docRoot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file path of the swf (with swf name) with [`stage.loaderInfo.loaderURL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#loaderURL).